# Do all C++ compilers support the async/await keywords?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, async-await, cross-platform, unreal-engine4

I want to use `async/await` syntax in C++ (UE4 framework), but due to cross-platform code I not sure that is possible... Or possible? If yes, how can I use it?

And also there are `await` and `__await` (`resumable`, `yield` and `__yield_value` also) keywords that highlighted in Visual Studio. What's difference? Maybe not all compilers supports this keywords or supports separately?

`gcc`, `clang` are accepts it? Or not accepts and I can just use macros for each platform individually.

Comment: No, not *all* compilers support `async` or `await` syntax.  GCC and CLang are only 2 of many compilers out there.  You should check Greenhills, IAR, Keil and Visual Studio to name a few.

Comment: The llvm & clang implementation is underway : see https://twitter.com/Eric01/status/867473461836263424 (May 24th, 2017 : "Coroutines are now in Clang Trunk!")

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`async` and `await` are language extensions proposed by Microsoft with several revisions, but current is [N4134](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n4134.pdf). This has not yet accepted into the standard.

The proposal is opposed by many like http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0158r0.html due to not being completely baked and having not been explored fully in a TS and there's competing proposals like [N3985](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n3985.pdf) which proposes coroutines that can be implemented within the existing language standard.

To my knowledge, the only compiler that actually supports async/await is MS Visual Studio.

As an update, clang 5.0 has support for the current draft co-routines proposal https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4663.pdf which has now been accepted as a TS and is progressing with an eye toward the C++20 standard.

Comment: Wow, you are indeed a Subject Matter Expert on this topic.

Comment: @AbhijeetNagre you can be the Subject Matter Expert by knowing where to look for proposals, subscribing to wg21 mailing lists and tracking gcc/clang changelogs.